# CreatedAtRoute results a null link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Somehow CreatedAtRoute results in a proper 201 code in CreatedAtRoute object, but 500 error code in reply to postman.

I've read most of CreatedAtRoute questions and allready tryed several solutions - but seems that none work for me (or i`m still doing something wrong).

```
//Get single method
[Route("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WorkerDTO), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WorkerDTO), 400)]
    public IActionResult GetSingleWorker(int id)
    {
        Worker workerFromRepo = _workerRepository.GetSingle(id);

        if (workerFromRepo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<WorkerDTO>(workerFromRepo));
    }

//Post method
[HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WorkerDTO), 201)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WorkerDTO), 400)]
    public IActionResult AddWorker([FromBody]WorkerCreateDTO workerCreateDTO)
    {
        if (workerCreateDTO == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Worker Object is null");
        }
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        Worker toAdd = Mapper.Map<Worker>(workerCreateDTO);
        _workerRepository.Add(toAdd);
        bool result = _workerRepository.Save();
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to add Worker");
        }
        //returns good 201 code but somewhy fails to link the uri(
        //var tst = CreatedAtRoute("GetSingleWorker" , new { id = toAdd.Id }, Mapper.Map<Worker>(toAdd));
        //return CreatedAtRoute("GetSingleWorker" , new { id = toAdd.Id }, Mapper.Map<Worker>(toAdd));
        return CreatedAtRoute(
            routeName: "GetSingleWorker",
            routeValues: new { id = toAdd.Id },
            value: Mapper.Map<Worker>(toAdd));
    }
```

Suposed to get 201 and DTO model as a result.
Actually getting a 201 code in tst object, but no resulting route and a 500 error in Postman.
"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values."

Comment: Could you please post the exact result that is returned when you call 'AddWorker'.

Comment: @Thangadurai
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

Headers:
Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
api-version 1.0
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 194
Content-Type application/json
Host localhost:5000
Postman-Token cfd96cee-280c-40ba-a693-6277547abb08
User-Agent PostmanRuntime/7.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I`m an idiot, sorry all.
In asp.net Core seems you need to specify a Name for a route to refrence it, instead of refrenceing method name)
so adding a Name attribute to CreatedAtRoute made the trick)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}", Name = "GetSingleWorker")]
```

After adding those - returns fine header, url and model object:)